# Separating line in doxygen manual

Tags: doxygen

I am documenting my code with `doxygen` and want to introduce a `separating line` after a short description. What command can I use to include a separator? I have seen a series of separating lines in the doxygen manual but cannot find the appropriate command.

Comment: I think you are looking for the <hr> tag, which is currently (as far as I can see) only supported for HTML output.

Comment: What would be the syntax for HTML. I have not seen any good examples.

Comment: <hr> would be the syntax (PDF documentation chapter 24)

Answer (score 1):

As noted in albert's comment, the syntax is `<hr>`.

Note that this does not work equally well in all output formats, but it does work in HTML. See albert's comment below.

Comment: It is not completely true, besides HTML it is at least in rtf (doesn't look nice) and docbook output present, in the LaTeX output it is missing though. When required please file a bug report / enhancement request (including a small example) in the doxygen issue tracker: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new

Comment: In the github master version of doxygen the `<hr>` does now also work for LaTeX.

Comment: @albert Thanks for the feedback again. 

Would you please consider adding your own answer, that you are happy with, and I will delete this one. Or editing this answer until you are happy with it. 

(I only added it so others would see that the question was answered, but this cycle of me adding your comments, and then you correcting it, is not very efficient. Thank you again.)